# Best way to redirect to new page after submitting data to db? angular/php/mysql

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, angularjs

After a successful angularjs form submission to a MySQL db using php I want to send the user to a different page.  What is the best way to do that?

php header (location: myurl)....   doesn't capture the data-

echoing - javascript window.location.replace(myurl)...  inserts the data, but doesn't redirect.

Comment: You have to have the redirect setup in your callback from the $http request in Angular.

Comment: You need to totally rewrite that script. Trying to fix little bits will take forever

Comment: "*header (location: myurl).... doesn't capture the data*"  What do you mean? by the time PHP sends the `Location` header, PHP has already accepted the form inputs. What capturing are you referring to?

Comment: Are you using ajax? And what do you mean with capturing the data?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you're submitting the form through AngularJS, it's better to handle this redirect from the Angular side, rather than trying to get the PHP redirect working with an AJAX request.

You can use Angular's `$location` service in the callback, after the POST request is successfully completed:

```
app.controller('TestCtrl', function( $http, $location ){
  var req = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'http://example.com',
    data: { test: 'test' }
  };

  $http(req).then(function(){
    // this is executed after the request is completed successfully

    $location.path('/success-page');
  });
});
```